# Shorthand for multiple choice predicates in clingo

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

Right now I have a single choice predicate that defines my search space.

```
#const nRounds = 3.
#const nPlayers = 17.
#const nSeats = nRounds * nPlayers.
#const nRooms = 3.
#const nDecks = 6.

nSeats { seat(1..nPlayers, 1..nRooms, 1..nDecks) } nSeats.
```

I would like to restrict this search space as I'm starting to run into performance problems. In my set up each each player can only appear in 4 "seat" predicates so I would like something along the lines of:

```
#for i in 1..nPlayers
nRounds { seat(i, 1..nRooms, 1..nDecks) } nRounds.
#endfor
```

which would basically turn into something like this internally:

```
nRounds { seat(1, 1..nRooms, 1..nDecks) } nRounds.
nRounds { seat(2, 1..nRooms, 1..nDecks) } nRounds.
nRounds { seat(3, 1..nRooms, 1..nDecks) } nRounds.
...
```

I could, of course, "spell this out myself" i.e. use another language to generate these lines but I don't see why this wouldn't exist in clingo.

The reason I am looking for a way to do this in the first place is because I expect that `(nRooms*nDecks choose nRounds) * nPlayers` is going to be much smaller than `(nRooms*nDecks*nPlayers) choose nRounds*nPlayers` which is in turn much better than `{seat(P, R, D)}` with its `2^(nRooms*nDecks*nPlayers)` which is what I started with.

Even with constraints in my code that restrict the actual possible sets I can end up with so that all three of these representations are equivalent, there are still performance benefits to gain from such manual search space pruning right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "for loop" you are looking for is a straight forward rule:

```
nRounds { seat(S, 1..nRooms, 1..nDecks) } nRounds :- S = 1..nPlayers.
```

Check the difference to your code with `clingo --text`

I would also advise you to seperate the `seat(P,R,D)` predicate into several smaller ones (depending on your problem.
Like each player is assigned a room `p2r(P,R)` and every room is assigned to a deck `r2d(R,D)`. This way you save a lot of unecessary combinations in your constraints later on. Of course my two predicate may not make sense for your problem but I'm sure you will find a combination to split your seat predicate.

Comment: Brilliant, so I imagine you can do the same with sets e.g. `S = (a;b;c)`? There are multiple decks and each is played in multiple rooms so I don't think this could be simplified much further. Think quiz night - the decks could be Biology, Chemistry, Physics, each played in parallel in multiple rooms by different people. I could split `seat(P,R,D)` in to `seat(P, ID)` and `round(ID, R, D)` but I don't think that would make any difference as ultimately `|ID|` would equal `|R|*|D|`, right?

Comment: Sure, just give it a try and test with `--text`.
`round(1..5). player(1..5). deck(1..5). room(1..5).
%Assign every player every round exactly one room
1{where(P,R,X) : room(X)} 1 :- player(P), round(R).
%Assign every room every round exactly one deck
1{what(X,R,D) : deck(D)}1:- room(X), round(R).`

Comment: Is there any difference between `{what(X,R,D): deck(D)}` and `{what(X,R,1..5)}`?

Comment: No, just more reusable and readable. And of course deck can be names not only numbers.